# GCC Compiler Taking Forever to Update

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew

I'm using homebrew to update my GCC compiler and it's taking a pretty long time... ~25min so far. When I first installed GCC it took around 45min. I have a 2019 Macbook Pro and from what I can tell there's absolutely no reason for it to be this much of a challenge. [Here's the activity monitor while it's updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMAqR.png). The bottom of my laptop is also so hot it burns my hand if I hold it there too long and the fans are going nuts. I have no idea why it'd be this strenuous of a process to install/update a C/C++ compiler? Anyone know why?

Comment: Because its a big file and a long process

Comment: The current C++ standard is about two thousand pages long of terse, typewritten text. The current version of gcc covers (mostly), what, six C++ standards? Even after accounting for significant overlap, you can do the math yourself, and set your expectations accordingly. Now, let's talk about C, and all other languages gcc compiles...

Comment: “The bottom of my laptop is also so hot it burns my hand” is why some manufacturers call them notebooks, not laptops.

Comment: 45 minutes sounds about right.  The compiler has grown more complex since it was first released.  I've seen it take longer on some machines; I don't recall it taking much less with the full `make bootstrap`.  I don't plan to do anything else while GCC is compiling, and I don't update GCC in an emergency mode — it needs to be at a time when it doesn't matter how long it takes.

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew is building GCC from source.  Building GCC is a notoriously costly procedure.  More generally, compilation of complex programs is sometimes used for stress testing and performance benchmarking.  It takes a lot of work.

The Homebrew FAQ documents the [conditions under which it will build from source](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-do-you-compile-everything).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Homebrew tries to install packages from pre-built binaries (as mentioned in John Bollinger's link). However, it sounds like you're running macOS Mojave (10.14), which [isn't supported by Homebrew anymore](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#macos-requirements). Ideally, you'd upgrade to Catalina or newer.